# Graphic issue with Windows 8 (Acer V5)

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, acer-aspire

I have an Acer V5-571G, recently my HDD crashed and I bought A new one. So I installed Windows 8 (with the same CD Key).

Now this is what I see:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CRbwHvC.jpg]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ngvdL5d.jpg]

I can have a clear view with Teamviewer from my other PC, so I installed and updated nVidia etc... But nothing is working.

What can I do?

**PS: On safe mode everything looks fine...**

Comment: This isn't a software problem it's very likely a bardware problem

Comment: I dont think so, I was on Fedora and everything was working fine... :(

Comment: PS: splash screen of windows is OK

Comment: Just because the splash screen doesn't have a problem doesn't mean there isn't a hardware problem

Comment: update the GPU driver.

Comment: When you were installing Windows8, did the screen look like that too?

Comment: No, when I was installing, the screen looks fine...

Comment: @RsyaStudios how to update the GPU?

Comment: I thought you'd updated the nVidia GPU already as stated in the question? The integrated GPU (Intel) can be updated from Windows Update. My advice would be to reinstall the OS since it was working during the install, so something must have gone wrong there, or if you can't, just Windows Update (though I'm not sure it'll fix it).

Comment: Is it any way to test the graphics card? both? I tried to test the intel GPU with OCCT but There was no errors... I tried to test the nVidia but it said that cannot creat the D3D...